# How to pass a closure as parameter recursively?

Tags: recursion, rust, closures

**The problem**

I am building the pre-order traversal for an n-tree, in such a way a closure is given to be executed for each node in the traversal.

My first approach was the following:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
pub struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    children: Vec<Node<T>>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn preorder<F>(&self, mut f: F)
    where
        F: FnMut(&Self),
    {
        f(self);
        self.children.iter().for_each(|child| child.preorder(f));
    }
}
```

However I am facing an error when calling the `child.preorder(f)` statement inside the foreach iterator.

```
error[E0507]: cannot move out of `f`, a captured variable in an `FnMut` closure
  --> src/lib.rs:12:62
   |
7  |     pub fn preorder<F>(&self, mut f: F)
   |                               ----- captured outer variable
...
12 |         self.children.iter().for_each(|child| child.preorder(f));
   |                                       -------                ^ move occurs because `f` has type `F`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
   |                                       |
   |                                       captured by this `FnMut` closure
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=09d6aba89f2bb729c527eaad20f22b26)

**Solutions I found**

Changing the header of the pre-order method to the following compiles perfectly, but it sets a Copy requisite on the closure to be used that I do not want at all.

```rust
pub fn preorder<F>(&self, mut f: F)
    where
        F: FnMut(&Self) + Copy,
```

Another way I found to workaround the Copy requisite on the closure is by using an immersion method like the following ([see it in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=bcbf65e85d48f22f700eb2ea53a18e3e)):

```rust
pub struct Node<T> {
    value: T,
    children: Vec<Node<T>>,
}

impl<T> Node<T> {
    fn preorder_immersion<F>(&self, f: &mut F)
    where
        F: FnMut(&Self),
    {
        f(self);
        self.children
            .iter()
            .for_each(|child| child.preorder_immersion(f));
    }

    pub fn preorder_mut<F>(&self, mut f: F)
    where
        F: FnMut(&Self),
    {
        self.preorder_immersion(&mut f);
    }
}
```

Sincerely, that is painful to watch. Basically because it implies to have two methods for each traversal implementation.

**What I want**

It would be great to be able to do something like this when invoking the pre-order method:

```rust
let mut result = Vec::new();
node.preorder(|n| result.push(*n.value()));
```

And the latest solution I gave works fine.

**My question**: is there any more elegant way to do so? Am I missing something? Or is OK to use the immersion approach?

Comment: I'd implement `preorder` as a method that returns some `Iter: Iterator` and just use `Iterator::map` for mapping a closure over it. Not exactly sure if it's feasible though.

Comment: How do you do store the current state of the iterator in order to know the next step? I was trying at first to implement Iterator for Node but I found out several issues when moving from a child to its brother. At least I did not know how to do so in a constant sized Iterator.

Comment: I don't think a constant (as in independent from your tree) size iterator is possible, but neither is your approach, unless you don't count stack usage. Off the top of my head you could just store the chain of indices.

Comment: Yeah exactly, that was my first approach (a list of iterators). Probably is more elegant than my current implementation. I am moving back to that point then. Thanks you a lot! :)

Comment: I would go with the latest version. The only thing I would change is making `preorder_immersion()` an inner function.

Comment: I will take your advice. Despite of the Iterator approach is great for iterating immutablely, I was wondering now how to implement the mutable iterator. As far as I could read it is unsafe to do so in a tree using iterators, so I would have to implement the preorder_mut using the immersion approach (as from now the inner function approach).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in a comment earlier I'd go with an `Iterator` based approach, while exploring I found this solution which is quite elegant in my opinion:

```rust
impl<T> Node<T> {
    pub fn preorder(&self) -> impl Iterator<Item = &Self> {
        Iter::new(self)
    }
}

struct Iter<'a, T> {
    left: Vec<&'a Node<T>>,
}

impl<'a, T> Iter<'a, T> {
    fn new(root: &'a Node<T>) -> Self {
        Self { left: vec![root] }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for Iter<'a, T> {
    type Item = &'a Node<T>;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let current = self.left.pop()?;
        self.left.extend(current.children.iter().rev());
        Some(current)
    }
}
```

We store nodes we have yet to yield in a `Vec`, in reverse so that we can use `pop` and `extend` which should be quite efficient. Whenever we yield a `Node` we add it's children to the remaining Nodes.

Instead of using it like this `node.preorder(your_closure_or_function)` you'd use it like `node.preorder().for_each(your_closure_or_function)`, but for the small price of an extra function call you get the whole power and toolset already built around iterators in Rust.